# Spring boot mongoDB jars

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, jar, spring-data-mongodb

What is the difference between these `Spring Boot` `jars`.

- spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb jar
- spring-data-mongodb jar
- mongodb-driver jar
- mongodb-driver-core jar

  What I understand in those all is that `mongodb-driver` is the java driver for mongoDB. And `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` is starter like spring boot has for many (`spring-boot-starter-web`, `spring-boot-starter-test`).

Can someone please explain their role in `Spring boot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**mongodb-driver-core:** The Java operations layer for the MongoDB Java Driver. Third parties can ' + 'wrap this layer to provide custom higher-level APIs.

**mongodb-driver:** The driver which allows you to connect to MongoDB databases from java applications.

**spring-data-mongodb:** The library you need to use Spring Data with MongoDB in your project, which might not be Spring Boot based.

**spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:** The starter for using Spring Data Mongo DB in Spring Boot, with everything you need for that.

Note that each of these libraries makes use of the other ones above, so it increases abstraction.

**See also:**

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongodb-driver-core
- https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/
- https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/